# How can show my id field in 8 charater length string

Tags: php

In my listing page I have to show the record ID in eight character length string. This needs to be combination of letters and digits. The first 4 characters need to be letters and last 4 need to be digits. For viewing purpose alone I need to show the record ID in this formatted manner.

If a record ID has less than 4 digits,  then add prefix `0`'s in front of them.

For example:

record #2 needs to show like `AAAA0002`.
record #10001 needs to be like `AAAB0001`.

The first part of 4 letters starts with `A`,
if the record ID has more than 4 digits, the respected characters need to be incremented in the same manner.

Can any one suggest me your valuable advice in this ?

Comment: Please post some more example. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: What would be the rule to map `10001` onto `AAAB0001`?

Comment: What is the meaning of `AAAB`? Why `A`? Why is `1` replaced by `B`?

Comment: i would like show my record id in listing page itself looks like pre 4 char and 4 digit in post order.  for eg: if consider 3 digit length, 101 shows like A01 suppose 200 looks like B00 etc. like this.

Comment: If you were just going to use numbers, you could have gone with: sprintf("%08d", $my_id);

Comment: Hi felix thanks for your post. the pre alphabets needs to same manner as auto increment,  so after a it needs to show as b.

Comment: for the first record it needs to have pre ooo's as well AAAA. I need a combination of 4 character as well as integer for my records id, instead of showing #135 i needs to show like this. this was my requirement.

Comment: for your explanation a -1 well deserved. Considering how you wrote 000, you are clearing trolling here

Comment: If the id is lesser than 4 digit then added padding in left of the string. Only thing it needs to shown as 8 character length string. for view purpose alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I hope I understood it:

You have record IDs which can consist of max. 8 digits. If an ID has less than 8 digits, it should be prepended with `'0'`. You can do so by using [`sprintf`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
// $id is 10001
$id = sprintf('%08d', $id); // 00010001
```

Then you want to convert the first four digits into letters, where (it seems) `0=>A, 1=>B,...`. You can create such a mapping with [`range`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
$char_map = range('A', 'J'); // array(0 => A, 1 =>B, ..., 9 => J);
```

To convert the digits, you can use [`strtr`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), and to only get the first four digits, [`substr`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$id = strtr(substr($id, 0, 4), $char_map) . substr($id, 4); // AAAB0001
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/lbMpmX2T)

Comment: Thanks Felix, you have given me a nice code. Let me check this kind of code in my scenario and let you know. Once again thanks for your valuable tips.